# Validation Problem in Struts 2

Tags: xml, validation, struts2

I have a date fields in jsp splitted into 3 text boxes , each text box corresponds to DD , MM & YYYY respectively.
So I have defined 3 String fields in my action to get those values.
Now I have to merge the three fields and for a date object to persist in Database.

Where I am stuck is how to validate in XML.
To validate individual text boxes I have used regex to check correct format of data.
It displays three error messages in case I do not fill date as I am not able to short circuit regex validations.

Also how to do validation like date should not be greater than current date .

can somebody post a sample code to short circuit regex expression for 3 different fields?
Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Rajiv

Comment: Why not just use the validate method in the action?

Answer (score 0):

validate DD to be between 01 and 31. MM to be between 01 and 12, YYYY to be whatever range of years you wish to allow.

Then use `new SimpleDateFormatter("dd-MM-YYYY")` when you concat your three strings together with "-"'s in between.